# Solr in Flask web app - Failed to connect to server - Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: flask, heroku, solr, pythonanywhere

I have indexed files successfully using Solr, and queried the core successfully by using pysolr. The code is working fine in the Pycharm Terminal. Now I am trying to convert the code to a web app using Flask on pythonanywhere.com. However when I put the following line in the code for the web app I get an error:

solr = Solr('http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts')

The error that I am getting is:

*pysolr.SolrError: Failed to connect to server at http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/select/?q=Sumedh&wt=json: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8983): Max retries exceeded with url: /solr/techproducts/select/?q=Sumedh&wt=json (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fa57c3c28d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))*

If someone can please help me in solving this error I would be really grateful.

Comment: You won't be able to use SOLR on `localhost` on Heroku. Try installing [an appropriate addon](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#search).

Comment: You won't be able to use Solr on PythonAnywhere that way, as there is no way to run Solr server there in a way that makes it accessible for other processes.